# Find child in a java Tree(recursively)

Tags: java, recursion, tree

thanks for check it out. What I want is to get the tree where root id is the id passed by param but its returning null pointer.

Tree settings

```
TreeIF<DoctorIF> tree = new Tree<DoctorIF>();

   setTree(tree);

   DoctorS ceo = new DoctorS(1, this);
   DoctorS two = new DoctorS(2, this);
   DoctorS three = new DoctorS(3, this);
   DoctorS four = new DoctorS(4, this);
   DoctorS five = new DoctorS(5, this);
   DoctorS six = new DoctorS(6, this);
   DoctorS seven = new DoctorS(7, this);

   TreeIF<DoctorIF> t1 = new Tree<DoctorIF>(three);
   TreeIF<DoctorIF> t2 = new Tree<DoctorIF>(four);
   TreeIF<DoctorIF> t3 = new Tree<DoctorIF>(two);
   tree.setRoot(ceo);

   t1.addChild(new Tree<DoctorIF>(seven));
   t2.addChild(new Tree<DoctorIF>(five));
   t3.addChild(t1);
   t3.addChild(t2);
   t3.addChild(new Tree<DoctorIF>(six));

   tree.addChild(t3);
```

Function to get tree or tree child. I got nullpointer when I'm searching id {4,5,6,7}.

```
private TreeIF<DoctorIF> getTreeChild(TreeIF<DoctorIF> tree_, int id){
    if (tree_.getRoot().getId()==id && id!=1)return tree_;
    else{
        ListIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> list = tree_.getChildren();
        IteratorIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> it = list.getIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            TreeIF<DoctorIF> subtree = getTreeChild(it.getNext(), id);
            if (subtree.getRoot()!=null && subtree.getRoot().getId()==id)return subtree;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

 @Override
public DoctorIF getDoctor(int id){
    TreeIF<DoctorIF> tree_ = null;
    tree_ = getTreeChild(tree, id);
    return tree_.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some comments to explain my changes:

```
private TreeIF<DoctorIF> getTreeChild(TreeIF<DoctorIF> tree_, int id){
    if (tree_.getRoot().getId()==id && id!=1)return tree_;
    else{
        ListIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> list = tree_.getChildren();
        IteratorIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> it = list.getIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            TreeIF<DoctorIF> subtree = getTreeChild(it.getNext(), id);
            //subtree might be null at this point
            //In that case, subtree.getRoot() will throw a NullPointerException
            if (subtree == null) continue; //This will prevent the NullPointerException
            if (subtree.getRoot()!=null && subtree.getRoot().getId()==id)return subtree;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! You should also check and upvote the other answer as well as it also has some valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is needlessly complex. It returns either the subtree if it was found, or `null` otherwise. So you don't have to check the id twice.

`getTreeChild` can return `null`, but you dereference it without checking, so that's probably where the null pointer exception comes from.

This should work:

```
private TreeIF<DoctorIF> getTreeChild(TreeIF<DoctorIF> tree_, int id){
    if (tree_.getRoot().getId()==id && id!=1)return tree_;
    else{
        ListIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> list = tree_.getChildren();
        IteratorIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> it = list.getIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            TreeIF<DoctorIF> subtree = getTreeChild(it.getNext(), id);
            if (subtree != null) return subtree; // No need to check the id again.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Your code also looks a little messy, with the Iterator like this. You can use a java for-each loop if you have your `ListIF` implement [`Iterable<...>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and have your `IteratorIF` implement [`Iterator<...>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

```
// ListIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> list = tree_.getChildren();
// IteratorIF<TreeIF<DoctorIF>> it = list.getIterator();
// while(it.hasNext()){
//     TreeIF<DoctorIF> subtree = getTreeChild(it.getNext(), id);
//     if (subtree != null) return subtree;
// }

for(TreeIF<DoctorIF> child : tree_.getChildren()) {
    TreeIF<DoctorIF> subtree = getTreeChild(child, id);
    if (subtree != null) return subtree; 
}
```